# How to add category exclusion to rss feed

Tags: rss

I'm trying to exclude certain categories from the mydomain.com/feed

Researching online I came across this code:

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/feed?cat=-3&cat=-12">Entries (RSS)</a>
```

Now the question is should I create a function (if yes what function to create) so I can exclude categories without having anyone to redirect to custom feed URLs

Answer (score 6):

In your functions.php add:

```
function excludeFeedCats($query) {
    if ($query->is_feed) {
        $query->set('cat','-3, -12');
    }
return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','excludeFeedCats');
```

Or use [Simply Exclude](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simply-exclude/) for more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look  on this plugin too [Ultimate Category Excluder](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ultimate-category-excluder/).i hope it'll helps you:)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I'm not a big fan of plugins anymore.. I already have around 30 plugins.. prefer to use php than plugins.